# Accessing option page localStorage from content script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to code a simple chrome extension but I'm experiencing some difficulty when trying to access the options.html's local storage from my content script "auto.js".

From what i've gathered (googling and reading Chrome's confusing documentation) this is only possible using:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage & chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener
```

Content script "auto.js":

```
var quantity   = ""
var shoe_size  = ""

function addToCart() {

chrome.runtime.sendMessage({localstorage: "qty"}), function(response){
    var quantity = response.qty;
}

chrome.runtime.sendMessage({localstorage: "size"}), function(response){
    var shoe_size = response.size;
}
...
```

My listener in "options.js":

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse){

  if(request.localstorage == "qty")
    sendResponse({qty: localStorage.qty});
  else if(request.localstorage == "size")
    sendResponse({size: localStorage.size});
  else
    sendResponse({});
});
...
```

The problem is my vars `quantity` & `shoe_size` are never set to the 'returned' values from the html local storage.

There are no errors given in my js console and i'm not sure on how to debug this. Any feedback is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Prefer `chrome.storage` (https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage.html) to `localStorage` since it can be directly used in content scripts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because codes after sendMessage is run right after sendMessage is triggered. They ARE set but it wont wait for response, they are set after the time you need them. I had the same problem with this here [Synchronously get Stored data from content scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15674342/655316). To solve it you can put whatever function you want inside

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({localstorage: "qty"}), function(response){
    var quantity = response.qty;
}
```

in order to see that it is set, test this:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({localstorage: "qty"}), function(response){
    var quantity = response.qty;
}

alert("waiting for a second, to make sure that response is ready ...");
alert("Not it is set:" + quantity);
```

Comment: I tried using the alert as you suggested but its blank. I'm sure i'm missing something obvious.

Comment: well, add an alert right after `var quantity = response.qty;` to see if you are getting response at all or not

Comment: Well, you have to solve this first. After getting response, have a look at my answer

Answer (score 0):

You're writing `var quantity = response.qty;` with a preceding `var` inside the sendMessage callback function. That will create a local variable with, coincidentally, the same name as the global variable. But it's a different variable. And the memory storing it will be freed as soon as sendMessage is finished, because this is only a local scope.

Leave the `var` away inside sendMessage.

Also, you're missing the semicolons on those global vars.

```
var quantity   = "";
var shoe_size  = "";
```

Other than that, you can use `console.log` in your content script 'auto.js', inside the sendMessage callback function. It will land in the console of whatever webpage is loading that script.