# Is there any way to postpone html rendering after execution of content script file?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have `js` file removing some element from html. The problem is that chrome renders the html before execution of my code so the page would shift a little. I want the shift to be gone. what should I do?
here is my manifest v2:

```
"content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
    "js": ["background_scripts/ad_blocker_by_selectors.js"],
    "run_at": "document_start"
}],
```

My `js` code is as below:

```
obj._remove_ads_elements = function(){
    obj._get_current_tab_domain_selectors(function(selectors){
        for(var i in selectors){
            if(selectors.hasOwnProperty(i)){
                var elements = document.querySelectorAll(selectors[i]);
                for(var j in elements){
                    if(elements.hasOwnProperty(j)){
                        elements[j].parentElement.removeChild(elements[j]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    })
};
```

can I make delay for html rendering?

Comment: Why are you using Manifest V2? It's deprecated, see [Manifest V2 support timeline](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/mv2-sunset/)

Comment: thanks for your reply. I will change the manifest as soon as possible. so my questions is that do you know any answer to my question in manifest v3?

Comment: Your content_scripts already declares document_start so the content script already runs before rendering. The delay may be caused by your code that reads the storage or sends a message because these API are asynchronous. The workaround is to use synchronous XMLHttpRequest, see this [ManifestV2 example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24150749). For ManifestV3 you'll have to use chrome.declarativeNetRequest.updateDynamicRules instead of webRequest.

Answer (score -2):

You can achieve this using Ajax request(xmlhttprequest) to get main html, so run your script before renderize.

Comment: The html comes from chrome I don't get html by Ajax